# Excel countifs ignore specific columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello together currently I have something like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B8:J8;"<>Y");0;1)+
IF(COUNTIF(B9:J9;"<>Y");0;1)
```

Hope I translated the german functions correctly. So my problem is now, under specific settings I want to ignore every 3rd line. In this case D, G and J. So a possible approach is with `AND`

Would work fine but with arround 100 lines I want to compare in one formula, I exceed the maximum range.

Is there a way to shorten it like:
`B8:C8 & E8:F8 & H8:I8`

Or is there a way to count the one which doesn´t contain `Y` but ignore the blank ones ?

Comment: What is the purpose of IF in your formula? Do you want to count the cells that do not contain 'Y' or you wish to return 0 or 1 if all cells in B8:J8 do not contain Y? You may also opt for a helper column and eventually apply your formula on to the helper column if you have 100 rows to process.

Comment: I want to count all rows which only contain Y or blank rows. I´m close to a solution. As soon as I found it I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by my own, sry:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B8:J8;"<>Y";B8:J8;"?*");0;1) + ...
```

The first parameter of countifs checks if there is any cell in the row which does not contain `Y` the second one also checks if there is any cell containing anything. This means it counts all cells which are not Y and not blank.
With the If in front I simply say If it found something wrong dont count that row.

I made a small addition for my self:

```
IF(COUNTIF(B8:J8;"?*");IF(COUNTIFS(B8:J8;"<>Y";B8:J8;"?*");0;1);0)+ ...
```

This way it checks also if a whole row is blank, if this is the case he doesn´t check further. That way blank rows are ignored.